# VC error while building on windows CIFS using jenkins

Tags: visual-studio, jenkins, cifs

I have jenkins master installed on linux. Have added windows slave using "launch slave agent via java web start" and updated service log on user with the same user i am using to mount CIFS on windows slave.  When I run the project I am getting below error.

> 19>Project : error PRJ0002 : Error result 31 returned from 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\bin\mt.exe'.

If I use local drive instead of CIFS then its working fine.

Anyone can help here?